# Enabling the chatter back

Tags: community, chatter

Would disabling and enabling the chatter back delete any content(files,messages) related to chatter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disabling / Enabling Chatter will not cause you to lose any data. However any features that rely on Chatter will not work and chatter data will not be accessible if it is disabled.